# Context Switches in Linux Kernel on Multicore

Tags: linux, multicore, context-switch

Does Linux Kernel perform multiple context switches concurrently, if required in parallel on more than one cores of a multicore processor machine? Any reference?

Comment: No, context switchess occur _nearly_ simultaneous. The context switch requires a lock on the process table, so only one process can be switched at a time. A second thread _may_ switch immediatly after the first, after having aquired the lock. (IIRC this phenomenon is called a "funneling" lock)

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you're right. On SMP system, multiple context switches happen concurrently. Each core can do context switch independently. Of course, if needed, spinlock_* is needed to protect critical section.

Maybe you want to know when will one core decide to do context switch, there are several situations:

(1) Interrupts happen;

(2) Exceptions happen;

(3) User process system call;

(4) In kernel space(not interrupt/exception context), there are also codes which call schedule() to give up CPU;

(5) ...;

Comment: @tod What experience are you talking about?

Comment: @tod, yeah, Andreas is right. Please describe your experience. So someone can help to analysis.